# How do you parse out output in R and read files in R package

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I have this function to read data from .csv file and output the result as json format:

My vcenter.csv file looks like this:

```
Host       Time    Cpu
server1 1406284200 0.0920
server1 1406286000 0.0920
server1 1406287800 0.0912
server1 1406289600 0.0928
server1 1406291400 0.0912
server1 1406293200 0.0904

output<-function(myname){
  library(rjson)
res<-read.csv("vcenter.csv", header=T, sep=',')

servers <- split(res, res$Host)
dumFun <- function(x){
  sData <- servers[x][[1]]
  if(nrow(sData) >0){
    # create appropriate list
    dumList <- unname(apply(sData[,2:3], 1, function(y) unname(as.list(y))))
    return(toJSON(list(name = x, data = dumList))) 
  }
}       
jsData <- lapply(names(servers), dumFun)
jsInd <- sapply(jsData, is.null)

p<-paste(jsData[!jsInd], collapse = ',')
p<-paste('[', p, ']')
print(p)
}
```

a. When I call this function remotely I get something like this:

```
[1] "[ {\"name\":\"server1\",\"data\":[[1406284200,0.387200012]
```

Is it possible to not display [1] and \ values in the output?

b.When I build this code with RStudio as a package with vcenter.csv file and install the package, when I run the output.R function, it does not see the vcenter.csv file. Where should I put the vcenter.csv? I tried putting it in the library directory, the same directory as the output.r script, not luck. I keep getting file(file, "rt") connection error. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `cat()` instead of `print()` to avoid the `[1]`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, when I use cat(), I get object not found error on the browser. However, when I d print, I get the results but there are other problems. Any other method other than cat() to get rid of [1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As Dirk said, use `cat()` instead of `print()`.
2. Put the file in the `inst` directory. If it is a data file, then a place people often use is `inst/extdata`. See http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages

   Then, in the installed package, you can find the data file like this:

   ```
   vcenter <- system.file("inst/extdata/vcenter.csv", package = packageName())
   res <- read.csv(vcenter, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
   ...
   ```

   Note that you don't have to parse the file in your package, you can also include it as an `Rdata` file, 
   see the *Writing R extensions* link above.

Comment: my package is called vCenter, I am doing this,vcenter <- system.file("inst/extdata/vcenter.csv", package = "vCenter"), still getting error not finding the csv file.

Comment: Most likely because you did not put the file there, or you did not install your package.